# Call Oracle Apex page and auto-log in from forms 12

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have Oracle APEX 5.1 and Oracle Forms 6i installed.

Now I am wondering how can I call Oracle APEX application from my Forms menu.

```
Option 1: Full URL to aplication + parameters username/password - not safe

Option 2: Full URL to aplication log in - not elegant.
```

What I am looking for is function that will take parameters `username,password, aplication ID, ...` and return full URL to aplication.

Is that possible / best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably do best to look at a new way of authenticating that avoids needing the password altogether, yet remains secure.  One way is to call a procedure from the Forms application that generates a single-use, short-lived token specific to the user, then pass that token to APEX along with the username.  The APEX authentication scheme then checks that the token is current and valid for the user, and if so allows access.

For example, the token could be generated as a random string, and stored on the user database record in hashed form (combined with the username as salt) along with a timestamp of when it was generated.  The authentication scheme checks that the token passed is the same as the one on the user record **and** that the timestamp on the user record is within the last N seconds.  It might then reset the token to NULL in the database.  The key point is that it must be "impossible" (read: very hard) for anyone to guess what the token is even if they can see the hashed value in the table.

Comment: Thank you for answer altho i am still leaning tovards recreaiting Apex login procedure that would generate me a valid URL which i could use to show my user his requested aplication without him needing to log in again (i have all his data stored from first login).

Comment: You mean a public URL?  OK.  But note my answer does not mean the user needs to log in again.  It means s/he is automatically logged in by the token on the URL - s/he will not see the login page.

Comment: The only thing i want to bypass is another log in step after my user is already logged to oracle forms. Becasue i have his credentials at this point and if he runs an Apex report from Forms menu i have to log him in automatically. What would be the most elegant way to do so?

Comment: That's what my answer does!